# Jwplayer skin, Play icon height issue

Tags: skin, jwplayer6

We are using Jwplayer 6, we are using vapor.xml skin. we have updated the play icon. But its not displaying correctly in chrome and IE,top and bottom of play button is cropping.
How can we increase the height of the play icon.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am currently experiencing the same issue and can not figure it out.

Comment: also looking for an answer..